# How to style the normal text inline with an h6 inside a <a>

Tags: css

I have an `<a>` element that inside has an `h6` and normal text. How I can style the normal text part?
I'm trying to use `:not(h6)` to put padding and border-radius:20px and others styles... see my css:

```css
.uagb-taxomony-box  {
  background-color:transparent!important;
  border:none!important;
  text-decoration:none!important;
  text-align:left!important;
  
}

a.uagb-tax-link h6{text-align:left!important;}

.uagb-tax-link:not(h6){
  text-decoration:none!important;
  padding:5px!important;
  background-color:#18419C!important;
  border-radius:20px!important;
}
```

```html
    <div class="uagb-taxomony-box">
        <a class="uagb-tax-link" href="https://dev3.netnerd.cat/tipus/desenvolupament-de-negoci/">
          <h6 class="uagb-tax-title">Desenvolupament de negoci</h6>
        " 16 Projectes "
        </a>
    </div>
```

but watch what is happening in the screenshot below:[image: the background get separated by h6]

How can I style well this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer. Try that

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you want the dark blue as a background and with curved ends only to the text, not the h6 element?

Answer (score 1):

You can give **display: inline-block to "a" element**. If you want to give **background to only text**. Then **put the text in span element** and give styling to it. Here is the updated code:-

```css
.uagb-taxomony-box  {
  background-color:transparent!important;
  border:none!important;
  text-decoration:none!important;
  text-align:left!important;
  
}

a.uagb-tax-link:not(h6){
  display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    padding:5px!important;
    border-radius:20px!important;
}

a.uagb-tax-link h6{
    text-align:left!important;
}



.simple-text{
  background-color:#18419C!important;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <div class="uagb-taxomony-box">
        <a class="uagb-tax-link" href="https://dev3.netnerd.cat/tipus/desenvolupament-de-negoci/">
          <h6 class="uagb-tax-title">Desenvolupament de negoci</h6>
          <span class="simple-text"> " 16 Projectes " </span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: But this puts all blue background in the 2 elements: h6 and normal text. I want only the text "16 projectes" to have the background.

Comment: @XaRz I have updated the code. try now

Comment: This is right. Then because I can't modify the code, I've opted to add the span with jquery.

Comment: @XaRz Oky wait let me see if it can be possible without you add span using jquery

Comment: @XaRz I tried but unfortunately in css, there is no way to select the text node. So, you have to add span through jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute`:

```css
.uagb-taxomony-box  {
  background-color:transparent!important;
  border:none!important;
  text-decoration:none!important;
  text-align:left!important;
  
}

a.uagb-tax-link h6{text-align:left!important;}

.uagb-tax-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration:none!important;
  padding:5px!important;
  background-color:#18419C!important;
  border-radius:20px!important;
  color: #fff;
}
.uagb-tax-link h6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="uagb-taxomony-box">
        <a class="uagb-tax-link" href="https://dev3.netnerd.cat/tipus/desenvolupament-de-negoci/">
          <h6 class="uagb-tax-title">Desenvolupament de negoci</h6>
        " 16 Projectes "
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: But I only want the text "16 Projectes" get the background. The problem seems that only with inserting and element (span) can then be styled. (with js or jquery).

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/16948533/developer has pointed I need to add a span here for properly style the no-h6 part.

Then i've used something like:

```
  $('.uagb-tax-link').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $textNodes = $link.contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    });
    var $span = $('<span class="text-no-h6"></span>').text($textNodes.last().text());
    $textNodes.last().replaceWith($span);
  });
```

And then css get's modyfied as:

```
.uagb-taxomony-box  {
  background-color:transparent!important;
  border:none!important;
  text-decoration:none!important;
  text-align:left!important;
  
}

a.uagb-tax-link h6{text-align:left!important;}

span.text-no-h6{
  text-decoration:none!important;
  padding:5px!important;
  background-color:#18419C!important;
  border-radius:20px!important;
}
```

Comment: Great. I hope it somehow fix the problem.